# I am having trouble multiplying dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having trouble multiplying the numbers in my two dictionaries. Here is my code:

```
prices = {
    "banana" : 4,
    "apple"  : 2,
    "orange" : 1.5,
    "pear"   : 3,
}
stock = {
    "banana" : 6,
    "apple"  : 0,
    "orange" : 32,
    "pear"   : 15,
}

total=0
for key in prices:
    print "price: %s*%s" % stock[key]*prices[key]
    total=total+stock[key]*prices[key]

print total
```

when I multiply stock by price , for orange it should be 1.5*32  and for banana it should 4*6 but I am getting an error message when I compile this code.

Comment: It's not clear how you are running the code, but it looks like you simply haven't indented the body of the for loop.

Comment: Please correct your indentation as that is a very important part of python.

Comment: Is that the actual indentation?

Comment: The `print` is wrong (not indented and the format string doesn't make sense), but otherwise your code is fine. EDIT: Actually you should be using `for key in keys(prices)` not `for key in prices` (which iterates key-value tuples).

Comment: nope, `for key in prices` actually iterates over keys [or key view in Python 3].

Answer (score 1):

```
print "price: %s*%s" % stock[key]*prices[key]
```

expects two values (one for each `%s` placeholder), but you provide only one (the multiplication result).

Furthermore, you need to put parentheses around your multiplication, or the `%` operator will only apply to `stock[key]`:

```
print "price: %s" % (stock[key]*prices[key])
```

or better

```
print "price: %d" % (stock[key]*prices[key])
```

Comment: @Pentazoid111: I suppose because you didn't show the actual error message, didn't format your code correctly, and didn't explain what exactly you wanted to happen. "It should be 1.5*32" is not very specific.

Answer (score 1):

Simple error

```
prices = { "banana" : 4, "apple" : 2, "orange" : 1.5, "pear" : 3, } 
stock = { "banana" : 6, "apple" : 0, "orange" : 32, "pear" : 15, }
total=0 
for key in prices:

    print "price: %s*%s" % (stock[key],prices[key]) 
    total=total+stock[key]*prices[key]

print total
```